# why is there 8128 8128 in Python code (what is different 'is not' to ' !=' )

Tags: python

```
def divisor_sum(num):
    total=0
    for x in range(1, num):
        if num % x == 0:
           total+=x
    return total
value = 0
total = 0
for i in range(0,10001):
    value = divisor_sum(i)
    if i != value and divisor_sum(value) == i:
        print(i,value)
        total+=i

print(total)
```

this code does not cause error in line 11
***(if i != value and divisor_sum(value) == i:)***

```
def divisor_sum(num):
    total=0
    for x in range(1, num):
        if num % x == 0:
           total+=x
    return total
value = 0
total = 0
for i in range(0,10001):
    value = divisor_sum(i)
    if i is not value and divisor_sum(value) == i:
        print(i,value)
        total+=i

print(total)
```

**if i is not value and divisor_sum(value) == i:**
but the code cause 8128 8128 
why do this when use 'is not'

Comment: why are you using `is` to compare equality? That isn't what `is` does. It compares *identitiy*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it's not at all intuitively obvious that two integers with a value of 8128 would not have the same identity.  It might have been a mistake for Python to use keywords that have meanings that don't map to common English meanings.